# bluetooth not finding devices nor being detected

Tags: bluetooth

I am a linux newbie. I am using ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to use bluetooth on the laptop however The bluetooth manager is not detecting any devices. When i try to look for my device from the phone, it is not detected. Can anyone please help me. I searched a lot and tried a lot of solutions but none worked. Thank you

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1050]
Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command. What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: There is a bug with this adapter in linux kernel. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1221995

Comment: What should i do in this case?

Comment: I am afraid nothing can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to unplugging the USB bluetooth? If it doesn't work, try and switch it off and switch it back on and switch the bluetooth on your phone as well.